# Issue about modification in table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, default

I do have some problem regarding saving changes when I'm going to modify my table. I'm using user defined default in my fields. I'm wondering that the reason why I can't modify my table because I'm using user defined default. When click the save button I always encounter this error message

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an option in SQL Server Management Studio to prevent you from doing changes that require a table to be rebuilt from scratch.

Go under `Tools > Options > Designers` and find the checkbox `Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation` and uncheck that checkbox.

[image]

It's not a bug - **it's a feature!** :-)

Comment: thanks mate.. yeah i know that i need to configure something in management studio but i can't point out where and what it is.. thanks a lot. it helps